# Capture a group in RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} size=(\d+)
```

and want to capture `(\d+)` for later use in `RewriteRule` or `RewriteCond`. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} size=(\d+)
RewriteCond $1 <1024 ## that $1 refers to (\d+)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `%` backreferences:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} size=(\d+)
RewriteCond ^ /%1 [L]
```

The `%1` backreferences a previously captured group in a rewrite cond.

Comment: Can I reference the capture group in the `RewriteRule`?

Comment: @CardinalSystem it should be the same thing, `%1` will backreference from RewriteRule as well